# What does the patriotism bonus do on some of the guns?

Tags: shoot-many-robots

There are some guns like the [Vicious All-American](http://shootmanyrobots.wikia.com/wiki/Vicious_All-American) that have a patriotism bonus. What is it? What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It does nothing, it's a joke stat.